# How to get a tabpanel inside a viewport with the ExtJS 4 class model?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, tabpanel, extjs-mvc

I got problems with the extjs 4 class model. I want to get a tabpanel within a viewport. I get it running by defining a own element and auto loading it with xcode. But I'm not getting it done inside the parent class itself.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.views.TheWindow', {
    extend  : 'Ext.Viewport',
    requires: [],
    border  : false,
    layout  : {
        type    : 'fit'
    },
    initComponent : function() {
        this.items  = this.buildItems();
        this.callParent();
    },
    buildItems : function() {
        return [
            {
                extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
                activeTab: 0,
                alias: 'widget.MyTapPanel',
                items: [
                    {

                        title: 'Artikel Manager',
                        html: 'test' 
                        /*items: [
                            {
                            }
                        ]*/
                    },
                    {
                        title: 'Artikel Manager',
                        html: 'test' 
                        /*items: [
                            {
                            }
                        ]*/
                    }
                ]
            }

        ];
    }
});
```

Whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
```

with

```
xtype: "tabpanel"
```

And you don't need to define alias, because you are not defining new class (Ext.define), but you just define item confgi.

Comment: omg. After trying around for a whole day now I got it running. Thx!